# Is it possible to show node id always with forcenetwork? (R)

Tags: r, networkd3

I am using the `forceNetwork` function within the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package and can't get the node ID name to always show. I can see it only if I hover the mouse over it. Is there any way to make it always show?

I am using this code from the [user guide](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#force):

```
# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
            Source = "source", Target = "target",
            Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
            Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
```

edit: It works really fine with @CJ  Yetman.

One more question...

Is it possible to put weights in the edges and show it?

Answer (score 3):

use the `opacityNoHover = 1` argument...

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, 
             opacityNoHover = 1)
```

The `Value` column in your links data frame determines the weight.

Comment: It works really fine! thanks @CJ Yetman. I updated my post with one more question.

Comment: The `Value` column on your Links data frame determines the weight.

Comment: `networkD3` does not have that feature. You would have to inject custom JavaScript to do that. There’s another question here asking the same thing last week.